# Find and sum date ranges with overlapping records in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a large dataset where I want to sum a count where records have overlapping time. For example, given the data

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": 'A', "start": '2018-12-10 00:00:00', "end": '2018-12-20 00:00:00', count: 34},
  {"id": 2, "name": 'B', "start": '2018-12-16 00:00:00', "end": '2018-12-27 00:00:00', count: 19},
  {"id": 3, "name": 'C', "start": '2018-12-16 00:00:00', "end": '2018-12-20 00:00:00', count: 56},
  {"id": 4, "name": 'D', "start": '2018-12-25 00:00:00', "end": '2018-12-30 00:00:00', count: 43}
]
```

[image]

You can see there are 2 periods where activities overlap. I want to return the total count of these 'overlaps' based on the activities involved in overlap. So the above would output something like:

```
[
  {start:'2018-12-16', end: '2018-12-20', overlap_ids:[1,2,3], total_count: 109},
  {start:'2018-12-25', end: '2018-12-27', overlap_ids:[2,4], total_count: 62},
]
```

The question is, how to go about generating this via a postgres query? Was looking into generate_series then working out what activity falls into each interval, but thats not quite right as the data is continuous - I really need to identify the exact overlapping time then do a sum on the overlapping activities.

EDIT Have added another example. As @SRack pointed out, since A,B,C overlap, this means B,C A,B and A,C also overlap. This doesn’t matter since the output I’m looking for is an array of *date ranges* that *contain overlapping activities* rather than all the unique combinations of overlaps. Also note the dates are timestamps, so will have millisecond precision and won’t necessarily all be at 00:00:00. 
If it helps, there would probably be a WHERE condition on the total count. For example only want to see results where total count > 100
[image]

Comment: Do you have some JSON data or are these table rows?

Comment: What about the intersection A B at the beginning (without C)

Comment: The above is just a cut-down example of the data as json, yes these would be table rows (note the dates are full timestamps, not just dates)

Comment: Good point @s-man - will update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c2e7e3acb377f47d553c2656511590ec) (uses the old data set with the overlapping A-B-part)

**Disclaimer:** This works for day intervals not for timestamps. The requirement for ts came later.

```
SELECT
    s.acts,
    s.sum,
    MIN(a.start) as start,
    MAX(a.end) as end
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (acts)
        array_agg(name) as acts,
        SUM(count)
    FROM
        activities, generate_series(start, "end", interval '1 day') gs
    GROUP BY gs
    HAVING cardinality(array_agg(name)) > 1
) s
JOIN activities a
ON a.name = ANY(s.acts)
GROUP BY s.acts, s.sum
```

1. `generate_series` generates all dates between start and end. So every date an activity exists gets one row with the specific `count`
2. Grouping all dates, aggregating all existing activities and sum of their counts
3. `HAVING` filters out the dates where only one activity exist
4. Because there are different days with the same activities we only need one representant: Filter all duplicates with `DISTINCT ON`
5. Join this result against the original table to get the start and end. (note that "end" is a reserved word in Postgres, you should better find another column name!). It was more comfortable to lose them before but its possible to get these data within the subquery.
6. Group this join to get the most early and latest date of each interval.

---

Here's a version for timestamps:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e33cf8da370ac8595e05679980f51c26)

```
WITH timeslots AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
            tsrange(timepoint, lead(timepoint) OVER (ORDER BY timepoint)),
            lead(timepoint) OVER (ORDER BY timepoint)     -- 2
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                unnest(ARRAY[start, "end"]) as timepoint  -- 1 
            FROM
                activities
            ORDER BY timepoint
        ) s
    )s  WHERE lead IS NOT NULL                            -- 3
)
SELECT 
    GREATEST(MAX(start), lower(tsrange)),                 -- 6
    LEAST(MIN("end"), upper(tsrange)),
    array_agg(name),                                      -- 5
    sum(count)
FROM 
    timeslots t
JOIN activities a
ON t.tsrange && tsrange(a.start, a.end)                   -- 4
GROUP BY tsrange
HAVING cardinality(array_agg(name)) > 1
```

The main idea is to identify possible time slots. So I take every known time (both start and end) and put them into a sorted list. So I can take the first tow known times (17:00 from start A and 18:00 from start B) and check which interval is in it. Then I check it for the 2nd and 3rd, then for 3rd an 4th and so on.

In the first timeslot only A fits. In the second from 18-19 also B is fitting. In the next slot 19-20 also C, from 20 to 20:30 A isn't fitting anymore, only B and C. The next one is 20:30-22 where only B fits, finally 22-23 D is added to B and last but not least only D fits into 23-23:30.

So I take this time list and join it agains the activities table where the intervals intersect. After that its only a grouping by time slot and sum up your count.

1. this puts both ts of a row into one array whose elements are expanded into one row per element with `unnest`. So I get all times into one column which can be simply ordered
2. using the lead [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) allows to take the value of the next row into the current one. So I can create a timestamp range out of these both values with `tsrange`
3. This filter is necessary because the last row has no "next value". This creates a `NULL` value which is interpreted by `tsrange` as infinity. So this would create an incredible wrong time slot. So we need to filter this row out.
4. Join the time slots against the original table. The `&&` operator checks if two range types overlap.
5. Grouping by single time slots, aggregating the names and the count. Filter out the time slots with only one activity by using the `HAVING` clause
6. A little bit tricky to get the right start and end points. So the start points are either the maximum of the activity start or the beginning of a time slot (which can be get using `lower`). E.g. Take the 20-20:30 slot: It begins 20h but neither B nor C has its starting point there. Similar the end time.

Comment: Really appreciate the quick response! I've looked at generate_series and doing it via a set interval doesn't really work since the data is continuous, the actual dates have millisecond precision. It _could_ be acceptable to use a 1 minute interval but ideally looking for a way that identifies the _exact_ overlaps then sums the count.

Comment: Side note - never seen dbfiddle before, very useful thanks!

Comment: Yes this is the reason for the disclaimer. I thought of some interval intersection operations but already didn't find a handy solution. I will have a closer look later if you'll still need it.

Comment: Also note the output in the dbfiddle above isn't quite right, the start & end should be the start & end of the overlap, not the min/max of the activities start/end. Eg the overlap A,B,C would have start/end of 2018-12-16 / 2018-12-20. An interval _could_ work but only if smaller, eg 1 minute, but that may kill performance on a larger dataset or date range. Hopefully this is even possible...

Comment: Found a solution! :)

Comment: This looks great at a glance - output is correct. Will have another look tomorrow and try to understand _how_ your query works. Also whether it will scale to 10,000+ records across several years

Comment: I would love to here how it works on a bigger data set. But I think 10000 shouldn't be a big problem with a good index

Comment: Clever solution, great explanation so have accepted this answer. Thanks! Will update if I find any issues with it

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged Ruby on Rails, I've put together a Rails solution for this too. I've updated the data so they don't all overlap, and worked with the following:

```
data = [
  {"id": 1, "name": 'A', "start": '2017-12-10 00:00:00', "end": '2017-12-20 00:00:00', count: 34},
  {"id": 2, "name": 'B', "start": '2018-12-16 00:00:00', "end": '2018-12-21 00:00:00', count: 19},
  {"id": 3, "name": 'C', "start": '2018-12-20 00:00:00', "end": '2018-12-29 00:00:00', count: 56},
  {"id": 4, "name": 'D', "start": '2018-12-21 00:00:00', "end": '2018-12-30 00:00:00', count: 43}
]

(2..data.length).each_with_object({}) do |n, hash|
  data.combination(n).each do |items|
    combination = items.dup
    first_item = combination.shift
    first_item_range = (Date.parse(first_item[:start])..Date.parse(first_item[:end]))

    if combination.all? { |i| (Date.parse(i[:start])..Date.parse(i[:end])).overlaps?(first_item_range) }
      hash[items.map { |i| i[:name] }.sort] = items.sum { |i| i[:count] }
    end
  end
end
```

I've updated the data so they don't all overlap, which generates the following results:

```
# => {["B", "C"]=>75, ["B", "D"]=>62, ["C", "D"]=>99, ["B", "C", "D"]=>118}
```

... So you can see items `B`, `C` and `D` overlap, with a total count of `118`. (Naturally, this also means `B, C`, `B, D` and `C, D` overlap.)

Here's what this does in steps:

- gets each combination of entries of data, from a length of 2 to 4 (the data's length)
- iterates through these and compares the first element of the combination to the others
- if these all overlap, store this in a hash

This way, we get unique entries of data names, with a count stored alongside them.

Hope this is useful - happy to take feedback on anyway in which this could be improved. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Thanks - interesting solution & definitely useful, will have a think but may not be an option doing this in rails for performance reasons, the actual dataset could be huge. Note the emphasis is less on which items overlap, and more on which _dates have an overlap_ along with the corresponding count

Comment: Cheers for the feedback @Dave - to be honest, I enjoyed getting stuck into it, so happy to have put it together nonetheless. Glad you've got the answer you were after!